# Navbar functionality?

Tags: html, reactjs, navbar, materialize, react-props

Please Help. I am trying to add functionality to my navbar so that if I click the menu button a side navbar pops out. It doesn't work. I have searched the web extensively. `signedInLinks` is a script that has the links used if someone is signed in. The boolean `true` is a place holder that will later contain `auth.uid` to check if a person is signed in (if you want to help me on this, please do as well - when I use this.state.links it throws an error.
How can I get my program to display a navbar with functionality (popping out menus etc)?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignedInLinks from './SignedInLinks';
import SignedOutLinks from './SignedOutLinks';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"
import M from  'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';

class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            auth : this.props,
            links : this.props.auth.uid ? <SignedInLinks /> : <SignedOutLinks />
        } 
    }



    componentDidMount() {
        const M=window.M;
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
            M.Sidenav.init(elems, {});
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (


            <div>

            <nav className="nav-wrapper blue darken-4">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"></link>

                <div class='container'>
                <a href="/" className='brand-logo'>DSHS</a>
                <a href="/" className="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile links">
                    <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
                </a>
                    <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">

                        {true && <SignedInLinks />}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
                {true && <SignedInLinks />}
            </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything at:

```
               <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    {true && <SignedInLinks />}
               </ul>
```

Try something like this:

```
                <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">

                    {condition ? <SignedInLinks /> : null}
                </ul>
```

The way above, you are going to check if your condition is true. If it is, it will return and render SignedLinks. Otherwise, you are going to render null.

Comment: condition is not defined though. hmm.

Comment: It was just as an example, you could change it to true for testing